# javafx datepicker in swing on swin panel

Tags: java, swing, javafx, datepicker

ok so i'm building this gui with swing components and i need to implement a datepicker on my gui.. after some research i found out that javafx has this really kool datepicker feature which seems very easy to implement.. i also found out that it is possible to implement some javafx features in swing.. but unfortunately all the tutorials i see for the javafx datepicker is implemented with a frame.. i wanna know if its possible to just get the javafx datepicker combobox on my jpanel... Can someone guide me on its possibility and the steps i need to take please.. thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use `javafx.embed.swing.JFXPanel` object for adding Fx datepicker into it and then adding this panel back to your swing frame or component.

Comment: thanks alot... i research on it and see its possible with this..

Comment: also can you please direct me to a website that has an example

Comment: sure, there are millions of link for this but we should refer oracles document, here is one https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/interoperability-tutorial/swing-fx-interoperability.htm